# Understanding Lenth Plot in R

Tags: r, experiment-design

I would like to understand how to interpret the Lenth Plot. From what I know from the [LenthPlot R page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BsMD/versions/2013.0718-1/topics/LenthPlot), this plot displays the factor effects with significance levels. But I don't really get what a spike crossing the ME (margin of error) threshold implies. Does it mean that a factor has a significant weight for a given model or is it the contrary ? I included a picture of a Lenth plot call using R. [image]